# IP rule for IPv6

Tags: linux, ip, ipv6

When I try to add an IP rule for IPv6 on my Linux system, it errors out:

```
$ ip -6 rule add fwmark 0xfab lookup 0xf
RTNETLINK answers: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I checked out the IP rule code; it issues a netlink message to the kernel. Probably I need to load some module, but I don't know which. What do I need to do to fix this?

I am using linux 2.6.37.3 built from kernel sources

Solution: By default linux build doesn't support multiple routing tables for IPv6. You need to enable CONFIG_IPV6_MULTIPLE_TABLES for multiple IPv6 routing table support.

Comment: Solution given in question works.

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 functionality is available to the system by the ipv6 kernel module. To check if this module is currently loaded in your system, issue the following command as root:

`lsmod | grep ipv6`

If you see ipv6 in its output, then the module is loaded.

Check your /etc/modprobe.conf and see if ipv6 is disabled.

```
alias ipv6 off
options ipv6 disable=1
```

It should be

```
alias net-pf-10 ipv6
```

Further check the interface specific configuration file: (If you are using a RedHat style distribution like Fedora, CentOS etc.,)

In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
```

In `/etc/sysconfig/network` file, if it exists:

```
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
```

And then restart `network` service And  restart the system for cleanly loading the ipv6 kernel module.

Comment: Nikhil, In fact Ipv6 is enabled in my linux box, and I have configured Ipv6 address too. Everything works fine , but I am trying to add an ip rule for Ipv6 which is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `lookup` as a valid option to any `ip` object.  Action for rules include `table`, `nat`, `prohibit` `recject`, `unreachable` or `realms`.   From the form of your command I expect you want `table`.  Try

```
ip -6 rule add fwmark 0xfab table 0xf
```